# I have a problem with the nuxt project deploy on cpanel

Tags: node.js, vue.js, nuxt.js, cpanel, nuxtjs

I have a problem with the nuxt project deploy on cpanel
Please, if anyone can fully guide me, thank you for running on the host

The image of the errors is available in the following links

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lf2n6.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hZkQU.png)

Comment: Do you try to use the `nuxt generate` command and serve the `dist` folder with that? What errors did you get If you tried something? Could you please provide what you try? Take a look at this link to ask better questions. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Did you followed this one? https://dev.to/themodernpk/deploy-nuxtjs-to-cpanel-2b51 Actually, there is a good amount of tutorials on Google, did you followed one of them? What is your configuration so far? We can't help you with just the result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve this problem, I installed the nuxt-start package before npm run build,

npm i --save nuxt-start

then
npm run build
and then
npm run start,
and the problem was solved, I said maybe this solution was needed for other people